# How to extract image frames from a bagfile?

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, ros

I am using ROS hydro on Ubuntu 12.04. After using the command

`rosrun image_view extract_images _sec_per_frame:=0.01 image:={IMAGE_TOPIC_IN_BAGFILE}`

I'm having an error when executing

`ffmpeg -r -b -i frame%04d.jpg .avi`

The thing is *I am not seeing the sequence of images* after I play the bagfile.

I ran

```
rosbag info
```

to obtain the topic in the bag file but when I run

```
rosrun rqtgraph rqtgraph
```

the /extract_image frame node is there all by itself.

When I follow the tutorials on http://wiki.ros.org/rosbag/Tutorials/... I get an error

`[FATAL] [1394583654.335465840]: Error opening file: play`.

After replacing play by "-**-clock**" everything seemed to go just fine but there are no **frames*.jpg** in ***/home/.ros*** hence *the sequence of images are still missing*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was my image topic /front_camera/camera/image_raw/compressed. This is what i had to do:

1) In a directory in which is writable (~/catkin_ws/bagfiles) type in the terminal

```
rosrun image_view extract_images image:=/front_camera/camera/image_raw _image_transport:=compressed
```

2) Then play the bagfile.(Though It can be done before or after) Then in the terminal in which rosrun was executed the following appears: "

```
> [ INFO] [1394806321.162974947]: Saved image frame0467.jpg
```

" The frames were made in that directory. process completed.